Flutter: vertical line in listview
I would like to know how to draw vertical line in side of listview items in flutter like it shows in image below


Here is sample of listview:

ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[500],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[100],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
    ),
  ],
)


sounds like Stepper to me.

@JohnJoe but stepper requires tap functionality, my case of use is simple list of FAQ points.

use StackWidget.

You can try this library another_stepper:
List<StepperData> stepperData = [
          StepperData(
              title: StepperText(
                "Order Placed",
                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              subtitle: StepperText("Your order has been placed"),
              iconWidget: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                child: const Icon(Icons.looks_one, color: Colors.white),
              )),
          StepperData(
              title: StepperText("Preparing"),
              subtitle: StepperText("Your order is being prepared"),
              iconWidget: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                child: const Icon(Icons.looks_two, color: Colors.white),
              )),
          StepperData(
              title: StepperText("On the way"),
              subtitle: StepperText(
                  "Our delivery executive is on the way to deliver your item"),
              iconWidget: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                child: const Icon(Icons.looks_3, color: Colors.white),
              )),
          StepperData(
            title: StepperText("Delivered",
                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                )),
          ),
        ];
    
        return AnotherStepper(
          stepperList: stepperData,
          stepperDirection: Axis.vertical,
          iconWidth: 40, // Height that will be applied to all the stepper icons
          iconHeight: 40, // Width that will be applied to all the stepper icons
        );


Try to add listview like below with text string characters count, without stepper
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 8,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Row(children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.add_shopping_cart,
                size: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  height: items[index].length / 2.8,
                  child: VerticalDivider(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  )),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(child: Text(items[index])),
        ]);
      },
    )

